# i'm getting integrity error, When sending data to POST api in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

when i send date to my api it throws the following error

```
 IntegrityError at /api/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: api_userinfo.user_id
```

**urls.py**

```
path('add/',views.UserAdditionalView.as_view())
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=50,unique=True)
    #phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    #phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True,blank=False,null=False)
    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=17,blank=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'username',
    ]

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

my views is
**views.py**

```
class UserAdditionalView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAdditionalSerializers
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):

     class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta,):
         model = User
         fields = (
        'id',
        'email',
        'username',
        'password',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
     
         )



class UserAdditionalSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     user = UserCreateSerializer(read_only=True)
     class Meta:
          model = UserInfo
          fields = (
             'user',
             'address',
             'zipcode',
             )
```

i'm trying to add more user info to database through the api.i used djoser for registering of user. whenever i try to add user through postman it throws IntegrityError . i cant find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like i suspected you have `readonly=True` here

```
user = UserCreateSerializer(read_only=True)
```

I think that might be the problem

Comment: sorry for that, i have added the searilizer now ,can you check

Comment: That solved issue , But i have  a new error.  'user': ['This field is required'],  what value is expecting in the user field..??

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply. I am not sure but you might have to overwrite the create method of your view to add user to the request.

Comment: Ok.I will try that